# How to change the time of a pomodoro timer when I change the button tab?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and I'm having a very hard time to learn the logic behind. I'm trying to make a pomodoro timer but I can't figure out how to change the time when I change the button tab to "break". I've been trying to do this for about 5/6 days now and I'm running out of ideas and my logic just don't work.

In my last attempt I created a function to see if the break button element had an "active" class and change the time if it did but it didn't work.

```
function changeTimeBreak() {
  const breakTab = document.getElementsByClassName('break-tab')
  
   if (breakTab.hasClass('active')) {
     minutes = 10
     updateCounterEl()
     return
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **JQuery's** `.hasClass` method. What you should use is Javascript's [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) **`.contains`** method.

I've edited your function. This should update the clock when `break-tab` button is **active**.

```
function changeTimeBreak() {
  let breakTab = document.getElementsByClassName('break-tab');
  
   if (breakTab[0].classList.contains('active')) {
     minutes = 10;
     updateCounterEl();
  }
}
```